# How can I dynamically rerender my api to my webpage?

Tags: reactjs, api

So I have this api and I am making a get request in my `ComponentDidMount()` to dynamically render it to my page and it works. The issue I am facing is when I make a post request to add items to the list, it does not show on my webpage unless I refresh it. The backend is my `data.json` so I don't know if that is the problem but essentially when I make a post request, I am adding data to my data.json and I want that to rerender on my page without me refreshing it.

```
componentDidMount() {
axios.get("/api/workboard")
.then(res => {
  res.data["boardLists"].map((item, key) => {
    // console.log(Object.keys(item)[0])
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      data: [...prevState.data, item],
      titles: [...prevState.titles, Object.keys(item)[0]]
    }))
  })
  // console.log(this.state.titles)
  // console.log(this.state.data)
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

addListItemHandler = () => {
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'api/workboard/0/list',
    data: {
      title: "Untitled" ,
      description: "No Description"
    }
})
.then(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
}

render() {
let board = this.state.data.map((item, key) => {
  return <WorkBoardContainer 
    key={key}
    title={item[this.state.titles[key]]["title"]}
    listItems={item[this.state.titles[key]]["list"].map((i) => {
      return i["title"]
    })}
  />
})

return (
  <div className={classes.App}>
    <AddButton addListItemHandler={this.addListItemHandler}/>
    {board}
  </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the fetching part as a seperate function and call it again once the post request is done.

```
componentDidMount() {
 // fetch data when component is mounted
 this.fetchData();
}

fetchData = () => {
 axios.get("/api/workboard")
 .then(res => {
  res.data["boardLists"].map((item, key) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      data: [...prevState.data, item],
      titles: [...prevState.titles, Object.keys(item)[0]]
    }))
  })
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

addListItemHandler = () => {
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'api/workboard/0/list',
    data: {
      title: "Untitled" ,
      description: "No Description"
    }
})
.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
 // fetch data again once post is done.
 this.fetchData();
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so I tried that and logically seems like it would work but it didn't. Thanks for the help though. I appreciate it!

Comment: What do you mean by it didnt work ? Isnt the data in being set to state when the function is being fired the second time ?

Comment: Also try to do a console.log of the fetched data in the render method to see if the data is being changed.